# Facebook friend request API's

Tags: facebook

I am writing an application which allows the user to login to facebook and fetch their details for contact sharing. Now i need to send a friend request to another user using facebook API's (programmaticaly). I had tested both OLD REST based API's and Graph Based API's but i couldnt find an appropriate one. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no friend request API. The only way for a person to request somebody to be their friend is through the Facebook web interface.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible with Android SDK.